# I have issue's when i will using Function callback

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, flutter-layout

i have custom button widget from different file, then i create **callback function** it might will showing pointer from main function, when i'm running i have issues this:
[Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Mgx.png)

and this code, main layout:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './increment.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void increment() {
    setState(() {
      _counter = _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Result = ${_counter}'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Inc(increment)
            // ElevatedButton(onPressed: increment, child: Text('-'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this widget custom:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Inc extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectInc;
  Inc(this.selectInc);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100,
      child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: selectInc(), child: Text('+')),
    );
  }
}
```

how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
onPressed: selectInc()
```

This is *calling* the function and using the result. You need to use the function only as a parameter:

```
onPressed: () => selectInc()
```

Since your `selectInc` method is a void function, the exact type the callback requires, you could also omit the anonymous function wrapper and pass your callback directly:

```
onPressed: selectInc
```

However, it seems you need some more type safety for the compiler to not complain. Make

```
final Function selectInc;
```

look like this:

```
final VoidCallback selectInc;
```

Comment: yay! thx dude it's fixed, can i ask 1 more?
why i can't use function without (), it's like selectInc not to be selectInc(), what is different?

Comment: @Dendimuhmd when you execute a function, you're referencing the value it returns.

Comment: @Dendimuhmd you could. `onPressed: selectInc, ` would work too.

Comment: @nvoigt without lambda here's should using VoidCallback but if i'm using Function callback it's should using closure () & lambda expression ()=> , current if i'm using Function callback without closure & lambda i get issues overflow like pict above, i don't know why it's happen

Comment: I don't understand. Did you try one of the two above ways to pass it correctly and you still get errors? If so, what is the exact error message?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439526/15872261)

Comment: thx dude it's really helped!